# Create objects in a loop with onclicklistener in JavaScript phaser game framework

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, phaser-framework

I'm trying to create an easy quiz game which displays a question and 5 variants of answers.

I work with phaser.js but I think it will applicable for JavaScript in general.

Here is my function that creates 5 buttons

[char_db.js]

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    button[i] = game.add.button((30+10*i), (30+5*i), 'buttons', actionOnClick(i), this, 1, 0, 2);
}
```

And here is my onclick listener which is doing pretty same for each button (but in feature it will do a different functions)

[index.html]

```
function actionOnClick (id) {
   //  Manually changing the frames of the button, i.e, how it will look when you play with it
   button[id].setFrames(2, 1, 3);
}
```

I got an error

```
[Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setFrames' of undefined]
```

My button array was declared in a very beginning

```
button = new Array();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: My suggestion is that if you want the function to return a value, you should return a value.

Comment: ...are you expecting `button[id]` to use the return value of `game.add.button()` before it's even invoked? You're calling `actionOnClick(i)` before the assignment to `button[i]` takes place.

Comment: @cookiemonster What is the right way to check what button is clicked in this case?

Comment: @cookiemonster Now i path just the name of the function actionOnClick, but i need it to check which button is clicked.

Comment: So an easy way is you need to pass the context [i] along with the callback "actionOnClick" so you can put it together in that "game.add.button" method. So you signature just needs another attribute:  `game.add.button((30+10*i), (30+5*i), 'buttons', actionOnClick, i, this, 1, 0, 2);`.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues with your code:

1) You're invoking the actionOnClick(i) function in the Button constructor, which isn't the required parameter type (Button expects a reference to a function here).

2) Your actionOnClick function assumes that an ID will be passed by the Button click event, but it won't. In Phaser the first parameter that will be sent is the object that invoked the callback.

With these two things in mind the following approach should work:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  button[i] = game.add.button((30+10*i), (30+5*i), 'buttons', actionOnClick, this, 1, 0, 2);
}

function actionOnClick (button) {
   button.setFrames(2, 1, 3);
}
```